# is there any way to take screen shot of an element of qt?

Tags: qt, screenshot, qwidget

I'm trying to take screenshot of an element of qt. I wonder is there any way to
take screen shot of a particular element of qt (QWidget)?

Comment: Read the ____ manual: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#grab

Answer (score 0):

In addition to `Plouff`'s comment, take a look at

```
void QWidget::render(QPaintDevice * target, const QPoint & targetOffset = QPoint(), const QRegion & sourceRegion = QRegion(), RenderFlags renderFlags = RenderFlags( DrawWindowBackground | DrawChildren ))
```

it might not be a difference but it is worth mentioning.